# Difference between $SO_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $SU_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, unitary-matrices

Is there any difference between the real Lie groups $SO_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $SU_n(\mathbb{R})$ or similarly the Lie groups $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $U_n(\mathbb{R})$. It seems that usually when talking about Lie groups we mean real ones but it seems like these groups should be the same in this case.

Comment: If $U_n(\mathbb{R})$ means unitary matrices restricted to real value entries, then I don't see a difference.

Comment: Usually unitary matrices are considered in the field of complex numbers. When restricted to real matrices there is no difference between those and orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967208/distinction-between-special-complex-orthogonal-groups-and-unitary-groups

Comment: @Javi is it just the case that SU defined over C is a real Lie group even though the entries of the matrix are not?

Comment: Yes, you can consider any smooth complex manifold to be a real smooth manifold of double dimension (and some [extra structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86970/what-is-the-difference-between-real-and-complex-manifolds) )

Comment: I meant to ask if it is a real Lie group but not a complex one. I apologise that wasn't made clear.